# What am I missing for Phusion Passenger to run my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Im jsut getting an index listing of my public folder. I've installed passenger with the tar file at /opt/passenger and used http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#tarball_generic_install.

Here is my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /opt/passenger/passenger-4.0.37/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /opt/passenger/passenger-4.0.37
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p353/ruby
  </IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName FSLSO-LOGSERVER
     # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
     DocumentRoot /opt/csdashboard/public
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://FSLSO-LOGSERVER%{REQUEST_URI}
     RailsEnv development
     NameVirtualHost *:443
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEngine on
     ServerName FSLSO-LOGSERVER
     # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
     DocumentRoot /opt/csdashboard/public
     RailsEnv development
     SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
     <Directory /opt/csdashboard/public>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Passenger Mem Stats

```
./bin/passenger-memory-stats
Version: 4.0.37
Date   : Sun Feb 23 12:53:06 -0500 2014

--------- Apache processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
1910  1     205.0 MB  0.4 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1914  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1915  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1916  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1917  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1918  1910  205.2 MB  0.4 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1919  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1920  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
1921  1910  205.2 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/httpd
### Processes: 9
### Total private dirty RSS: 2.86 MB


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


--- Passenger processes ---

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, SELinux strikes again.